# Table of tablenames

Tags: postgresql, database-design

im using a platform called CKAN which saves datasets. When a dataset is added it creates a table with a (seemingly) random name. There are certain datasets that I want to use the data from. Therefore I want to map the relation between the table in another table and the data that is inside. 
I would like to use this mapped variable (table name) in a select query as FROM statement.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT tablename FROM mappingtable WHERE id=1)
```

How do I do this?
Edit: As what kind of data type do I store the table name?

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that

Comment: FWIW According to the docs, CKAN does have an application catalog (which they call METADATA) which has a restful json API.

Comment: As you're mentioning postgresql, have a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql/34419 where several ways of acquiring table names are described.